# Weakest conditions on a function so that integral is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded set and let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. What are the weakest conditions of $f$ so that
$$\int_{\Omega}uvf \leq C\lVert u \rVert\lVert v\rVert$$
holds for all $u, v\in L^2(\Omega)$, where the norms are on $L^2(\Omega)$?

Obviously $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ suffices. But what are the weakest it can be? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I mean for every $u,v \in L^2(\Omega).$

Comment: Thank you, I deleted my comment.  Now is $\Omega$ a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with Lebesgue measure, or something else?

Comment: can you think of any example where f could be unbounded and your inequality would hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition that $f\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ is the weakest possible. Suppose $f\notin L^\infty(\Omega)$, so for any $y$ we have some set $S_y$ of nonzero measure on which $|f(x)|>y$. Assume WLOG that $f(x)$ is positive on $S_y$, so $f(x)>y$. Then let $u_y$ be the indicator function of $S_y$ and $v\equiv 1$. This gives us
$$\int_\Omega u_y vf\ge y\cdot m(S_y)=\frac{y}{m(\Omega)}\|u_y\|\|v\|$$
so letting $y\to \infty$ we see that no $C$ suffices to make the desired inequality hold.